# Get_Post and shortcodes

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I'm trying to get a list of IDs for posts by a specific user. I am using the following code:

```
    <?php
$args = array(
       'posts_per_page' => 5,
       'orderby' => 'date',
       'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
       'author' => bp_get_following_ids(array( 'user_id' => get_current_user_id() ) ),
       'post_type' => array ('user_images', 'post'),
       'fields' => 'ids',
        );                 
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
echo do_shortcode('[justified_image_grid preset=1 load_more=click recent_posts=yes post_ids='.$myposts.']');?>
```

But does not appear to be working any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the shortcode, but it probably expects a comma-separated string of post IDs:

```
implode( ',', $myposts )
```